# MySQL Query phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a SQL query that will search for user id and populate the query with the username.

These are my tables:

- Table Names: 'users' and 'schedule'

[image]

This is how I want it to look like, where 'schedule' table now shows the username instead of the user's ID

[image]

Comment: It is a simple inner join my friend.

Comment: @Hamidreza: the most appropriate solution involves two joins; if the engineer and sales columns are defined as NOT NULL, and there is  foreign key defined and enforced, then INNER JOINs will work. In the more general case, we'd usually want to use OUTER JOIN, so that the schedule rows are returned even when matching rows are not found in the users table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT s.REFID, s.jobnum, s.customer, u1.username AS engineer, u2.username AS sales
FROM   schedule s, users u1, users u2
WHERE  s.engineer=u1.id
  AND  s.sales=u2.id
```

You need to reference the `users` table two separate times, since you are checking in one sub-query for the engineer's username, and then checking in a separate sub-query for the salesperson's username.

Here is a link to an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84bf8f/1) that shows the result of the query's execution.  It matches up with what you were looking for.  I hope this helps.

Comment: NOTE: The inner join operations will exclude rows from schedule that don't have a matching row in users, that is, where the engineer column or the sales column is NULL or has a value not found in the id column of the users table. If the engineer and sales columns are defined as NOT NULL and there are foreign key constraints defined and enforced, then INNER JOINs are appropriate. In the more general case, where we don't have that guarantee, and we want to return rows from schedule including rows that don't have a match, then we'd need  to use OUTER JOINs.

Comment: @spencer7593 - You are correct.  Those rows would be excluded in the case that matching rows in `users` are not found.  I should have written the caveat in my response, but your updated answer seems to explain that well.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Following Query will give you the expected result:

```
SELECT 
    s.refid as refid, 
    s.jobnum as jobnum, 
    s.customer as customer, 
    u_engg.username as engineer, 
    u_sales.username as sales 
FROM 
    user u_engg join schedule s on u.id = s.engineer join 
    user u_sale on u_sale.id = s.sales
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select sc.REFID, sc.jobnum, sc.customer, us.username as engineer, us.username as sales
from schedules as sc
left join users as us on sc.engineer = us.ID and sc.sales = us.ID
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, since its looking for rows in users that has an ID column value that matches both the engineer and sales columns in the schedule table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.refid, s.jobnum, s.customer, u.username engineer, u.username sales 
FROM schedule s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u 
ON s.engineer = u.id AND s.sales = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to reference the `users` table two times. One JOIN to get the `engineer` username, and a second JOIN to get the `sales` username.

Something like this:

```
-- return all rows from schedule, and lookup of username where available
SELECT s.REFID
     , s.jobnum
     , s.customer
     , e.username AS engineer
     , a.username AS sales
  FROM schedule s
  LEFT
  JOIN users e
    ON e.id = s.engineer
  LEFT
  JOIN users a
    ON a.id = s.sales
```

Using a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` ensures that the rows from schedule will be returned when there isn't a matching row in the users table. For example, if you had a NULL in the sales column of a row in schedule, there wouldn't be a matching row in the users table. With an `[INNER] JOIN`, the row from schedule would not be returned. But the query above does return the row, but with a NULL for the username when matching rows are not found.

If the engineer and sales columns are defined as NOT NULL, and foreign keys are defined and enforced, then the LEFT keyword can be omitted from the query above. In the more general case, where foreign keys are not enforced (e.g. MyISAM) or not defined, or the columns are nullable, we'd generally want the LEFT keywords.

---

**UPDATE**

Removing the LEFT keywords from the query will produce a query equivalent to that in the answer from Alvin Lee, which implements INNER JOIN operations.

The query from Alvin Lee will EXCLUDE rows from schedule that have a value in the engineer or sales column that is NULL, or has a value that does not match a value found in the id column of the users table.

To identify if any rows in the schedule table are not being returned by the query using an INNER JOIN, you can run a query that does an anti-join pattern.

```
-- find rows in schedule that don't have matching row in users
SELECT s.REFID
     , s.jobnum
     , s.customer
     , s.engineer
     , s.sales
  FROM schedule s
  LEFT
  JOIN users e
    ON e.id = s.engineer
  LEFT
  JOIN users a
    ON a.id = s.sales
 WHERE a.id IS NULL
    OR e.id IS NULL
```

Comment: all of these are producing "NULL" where the username should be. I don't understand. I set both users.id and schedule.engineer and schedule.sales to all INT(8).

Comment: @bagofmilk: I suggest you verify that the number of rows returned by the query in the selected answer (using INNER JOIN) matches the number of rows in the schedule table. As I explained in my answer, the INNER JOIN is going to EXCLUDE rows that don't have a match. The query I provided will return all of the rows from schedule.